# Variable Initialization Bug?

Tags: c

So I declared a variable as an integer and initialized it to 0. When I tried printing the value of that variable, it gave me an incredibly high number. int

```
x=0;
printf("%d", &x);
```

This is what I did. Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we are using the `&x`, it will refer the address of the x . we need to print the value of x then use this,

```
 printf("%d", x);
```

In scanf() function, only we need to use `&x`, to locate the memory address to store the value.

Comment: Oh okay. I completely forgot about that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The operator '&' represent the address of that variable. we need, the actual value of that variable use like this...

```
            printf("%d",x);
```

Answer (score 2):

You print the address of the x so it will print the address during the compile time it will display the warning 
                                                                                 `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]`
So use following
`printf("%d",x);`

Answer (score 2):

Please print the value of X instead address like printf("%d",x);